# My pictures disappeared

Tags: includegraphics, dvi, ps

I'm writing a text and everything was fine but today two files named "Main.out.ps" and "Main.dvi" appeared in my main folder. My problem is that in the Main.pdf my images that I inserted using `\ includegraphics` disappeared.

I suspect the two files you mention have something to do with it. Since it is my thesis I am using a lot of packages, and I don't know if any package does not allow `\graphicx` to work correctly.

Im using this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,spanish,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[top=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in, bottom=1in]{geometry} % Tamaño de papel y margen
\usepackage{bachelorstitlepageUNAM} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\chapter} % Config titlesec
    {\Large\bfseries}   % 
    {\huge \thechapter} % 
    {20pt}              % 
    {\huge}             % 
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} 
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{textgreek} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[es-tabla,es-nodecimaldot]{babel} \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposici\'on}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corolario}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}[section]
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\AtBeginDocument{\abovetopsep=5pt}
\usepackage{ifthen} % \if \then \else
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{todonotes} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{table}{Tabla}{Tablas} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
```

Is is possible that one of these packages prevents `\graphicx` from working well?

! LaTeX Error: File `fig2' not found.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \includegraphics{fig2}

The message says this, but the image called fig2 is in the folder

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Could you add more details, please? It is probable that you have simply changed the compilation output from PDF into PostScript, but we may only guess...

Comment: a .dvi file is the output from latex, to get pdf you were probably using pdflatex. In either case included graphics will not simply disappear with no warning, you should show any messages from the log file

Comment: Not related but you have loaded `babel` twice. In addition a good idea is try to create a Minimal Working Example that shows your problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Investigating a bit on the subject it seems that the problem was with the operating system (linux), I moved the project to overleaf and it compiled perfectly

Comment: That makes no sense as overleaf is also using Linux. 9lus overleaf uses pdflatex by default

Comment: I can not find another explanation, I ran it on another machine with texmaker on Windows and also compiled.  I see many choose to copy paste the code into a new .tex, in my case I moved to overleaf.

Comment: Then it is important to know exactly what latex you installed. Plus noone uses PS or dvi anymore

Comment: Sounds like a possible path an/or permissions issue. Check your logs.